# latex() in sympy. How to get \frac and not \\frac

Tags: python, latex, sympy

```
from sympy import *

x, alpha = symbols('x alpha')

latex(alpha/x)

Out[1]: '\\frac{\\alpha}{x}'
```

That doesn't work in latex. What do I do to get the proper output, i.e.: '\frac{\alpha}{x}' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct an output (`repr` escape some characters, `\` in this case.). Try to print it.

```
>>> x = '\\frac{\\alpha}{x}'
>>> x
'\\frac{\\alpha}{x}'
>>> print(x)
\frac{\alpha}{x}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

Write:

```
print latex(alpha/x)
\frac{\alpha}{x}
```

Sorry about bothering you guys!